# Web Application UI - Layouts with 100% Height

Tags: html, css

I have seen applications that consume all the available space of browser window without any scroll bars on browser window, but scroll bars for specific divs (for instance, jsfiddle, which uses scroll bars for html, css, javascript and results divs but no browser window scroll bars). I am trying to develop such layout for my application and I have tried some keywords like Application style UI, 100% Height width layouts, fluid layout but none of them seems to return desired results. Pardon me but as a beginner I have to ask this. Is there a specific term for such layouts. I did came across few techniques and jquery plugins to achieve this but still wondering what would be the best way to go about it. Links suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic stuff.

First you have to set the height property of the *html, body* in CSS

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

The *overflow* to *hidden* will hide the scrollbars for your window.

Then you define a div in your HTML and assign the div a classname like *.foo*

```
.foo {
    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

By setting the *overflow* to *auto*, your div will take care of the scrolling of it's content.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/mXU3f/

Comment: really?? I thought there would be more to this.. since the posts I read about application style layout really made me think so..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post. The selected answer above is a bit too simplistic for a full screen web application UI.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Some basic CSS gets you pretty far in building your full screen, 100% height, or whatever you want to call it, web application UI.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help as i understaind you:

html:

```
    <div id="container">
<div class="box">
    <p>
        "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
        #container {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        height: auto !important;
        bottom:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        background-color:red}

.box {
    margin:50px;
    height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position:relative;
background-color:green;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```